# Make a borderless JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

Any parameter to set A JFrame's border/frame thickness or existence and still keep the title bar intact? I want an almost borderless frame with a thin blue line [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P57Xb.png) and [not like the default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OUQh.png) border.

If JFrame isn't the way to go, what is a good way to achieve that? (preferably that is compatible with WindowBuilder but that's probably asking for too much).

A search barely yields any mention and related questions on SOF don't seem to have answers so I thought I'd try to get a good answer once and for all.

Answer (score 1):

[`JFrame#setUndecorated`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated-boolean-)

> Disables or enables decorations for this frame.
>
> This method can only be called while the frame is not displayable. To make this frame decorated, it must be opaque and have the default shape, otherwise the IllegalComponentStateException will be thrown. Refer to Window.setShape(java.awt.Shape), Window.setOpacity(float) and Window.setBackground(java.awt.Color) for details

Please, consult the available documentation

Please note, you will become responsible for providing the title bar yourself, should you want it

> A search barely yields any mention and related questions on SOF don't seem to have answers

[Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java+borderless+window&oq=java+bordless&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5382j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) provides a number of promising hits

Comment: Really interesting features but still, Window.setShape() is default, Window.setOpacity() controls the opacity of the window and its contents and Window.Background() changes the background color behind the whole thing.

On the other hand, Window.setUndecorated(true) got rid of the whole frame beautifully but i lost the top bar (where the close button is) and the whole application is forces to (0,0) top left corner of screen.

Anyway to get back the bar at the top? (I can't remember the official term..)

Comment: But still what? I've just quoted the docs, which you should have a read of

Comment: I read the every single one of them and the related suggestions. Did i miss something? I'll go over it again.

Comment: Have you tried using `setUndecorated`? This is the closest you will get to a "boardless" window in Swing

Comment: Yeah, you didn't see it because i had to edit (sorry about that) but I used setUndecorated and like I said, it got rid of the border and the close button and everything and forced the program to the top left corner. I'll keep looking into setUndecorated but is there any way to get the close button back with setUndecorated(true)?

Comment: @ifyoudontmind Nope and this is the only method available to change the frame decorations without writing your own look and feel delegate

Comment: @ifyoudontmind You can make a `JButton`, and when it is clicked, call `System.exit(0)`, which will terminate the program, thus causing the window to close. you can also use `dispose()`, which closes only the window you are on.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching to NetBeans and learning some Photoshop basics which you'll need thanks to a comment by @MadProgrammer

> writing your own look and feel delegate

and ended up exactly with what you mentioned @theProgrammer101

> You can make a JButton, and when it is clicked, call System.exit(0) , which will terminate the program

You can create a similar button for minimize action as well as your own drop down menus that are totally custom made and you won't need to rely on the default JFrmae window in case that bothers you too (I found it horrid).

check out this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FOp_RVrAq0&index=1&list=PLZAdaq3vS0fon3IVjAEzzrmvJmA9aHY-4) for a good NetBeans tutorial with an nice example of writing your own look and feel delegate and this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7waNfsMXHU&list=PL3jDvU7Nxe6EYGF2C-x0eBMxK-8E22zM-&index=1) for a great tutorial on getting started with Photoshop which is critical to GUI creation.

Thought i'd round up some of my research for anyone else who's just getting into GUI's.